# How to change the URL from “localhost” to something else, on a local system using Flask?

Tags: windows, localhost, hosts-file

On a Windows machine, there's a system running on the local FLask server, but while the application is running on localhost.

While the Default I would expect the URL to be like this based on the directory structure:

```
http://localhost/swagger
```

But The developer has managed to do this:

```
http://ap-mispro/swagger
```

So instead of localhost, the URL says ap-mispro.

And both URLs work fine.

But How is the second URL at Flask/swagger works and how to setup similar stuff I know about wammp server and it can done through ini file but to do same for flask ?

Comment: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-edit-hosts-file-in-windows-mac-or-linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can perform this by modifying c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Simply replace localhost with ap-mispro it should look like :-

```
127.0.0.1 ap-mispro
```